# Virtualbox breaks host connections

Tags: virtualbox

Attempting to run Kali as a guest on VirtualBox (5.1.14) on a Windows 7 host.
When adding the wifi adapter (TP Link WN722n) through the machine's settigns->usb ports, then starting the machine, the host loses the connection, and displays "no adapters connected" on the network notification tray icon.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

I should point out that this adapter is the only adapter I use. Do I have to have 2 separate adapters, one for a guest and one for the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One device can't be connected to two machines, be it physical or virtual. Connecting anything to a VM disconnects it from the host first.

Try setting adapter mode to *Bridged* in VM's network settings. It will connect VM to the same network as the host.